# How to prevent C# compiler from removing internal constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, compiler-optimization, internal

I have a public class with 2 constructors: The default (without parameters), which is internal, and a different one, which is public.
The default constructor calls the other one with some default values.

I call the internal constructor using reflection, so it's not used anywhere in the assembly statically (only by reflection).

When I make the reflection call, I'm getting:

```
System.MissingMethodException
    Message=No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

I know of two workarounds:

1. Make the constructor public (but I don't want the users of this assembly to use it).
2. Call the constructor from some public method (I have many classes like this one, so I don't want to write a lot of this ugly useless code).

Any better solutions to this problem?

It's worth mentioning that if the default constructor is public, I don't get that exception.

Thanks,

Boaz.

Comment: The C# compiler does not remove code.  Use ildasm.exe to convince yourself.

Comment: Show us the code that results in this exception. Are you supplying the correct `BindingFlags` in your reflection calls?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know ildasm. I could find the default constructor there, but I still get a MissingMethodException. And I don't get it if it's public.

Comment: When exactly do you get that error?

Comment: When I use the reflection call.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Indeed I was mistaken to think this a compiler optimization. It actually was a wrong reflection call. Using Activator.CreateInstance(type, true) works for me to find both public and non public constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor is not removed, probably in the search of your constructor you should specify the flag `BindingFlag.NonPublic`.

```
    class xxx
    {
        private xxx() :
            this(10)
        {
        }

        public xxx(int value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(xxx), true);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Activator.CreateInstance have an overload with a boolean where you can specify if you want to call a non public constructor.

```
public static Object CreateInstance(
    Type type,
    bool nonPublic
)
```

Activator.CreateInstance(type, true) will call the constructor both if it is public or private\internal\protected.

Comment: Thanks. That's true. I have other such classes with public default constructors. I've tried to set (BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public) but it only finds the NonPublic ones.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance(type, true) will call the constructor both if it is public or non public.

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler does *not* remove any constructors for you. Open up the assembly in Reflector and I'm sure you'll see the constructors you've created.

I think it's rather more likely that the reflection code you're using to find the constructor isn't including `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. Sample code to show how it *can* work:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Foo
{
    internal Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo constructor");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctor = typeof(Foo).GetConstructor
            (BindingFlags.NonPublic |
             BindingFlags.Public |
             BindingFlags.Instance,
             binder: null,
             types: new Type[0],
             modifiers: null);
        ctor.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

EDIT: To pass binding flags to `Activator.CreateInstance`, you need to use a different overload, like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo),                                 
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                         BindingFlags.Public |
                         BindingFlags.Instance,
                         binder: null,
                         args: null,
                         culture: null);
```

(Or you can use the `CreateInstance(type, true)` as mentioned in comments.)

Comment: Thanks. However, when I use Activator.CreateInstance(type, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public), it only finds NonPublic and doesn't find a public constructor for types with public ones.

Comment: @brickner: I believe you're actually just calling the wrong Activator.CreateInstance overload, and it's trying to pass the binding flags as arguments. Example coming...

Comment: @brickner: One thing to learn from this question: instead of assuming you know what's going on (the compiler removing a constructor), post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. That way it's far easier for us to work out what's wrong and help you correct the issue.